# Android screen orientation according to mobile screen width

Tags: android, cordova

I'm creating an aplication with `Phonegap`. The point is if I can put a limit for screen orientation namly I want that the device can't change orientation to landscape unless the device screen width is more than 480px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. You have either screen rotation, or off. Not conditionally on. You can change your GUI of your app, depending on screen rotation and size.

Your question is to general to give a specific answer. But if you want to see an example, check out my repo jpHolo. It features an interface for smartphones and tablets and you can add code for screen changes easily.

https://github.com/teusinkorg/jpHolo